# AngularJS Route shows next view and then sends be back to previous view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-1.5

Using what I thought was a basic route, but it don't like me.

```
    .config([
        '$routeProvider',
        function($routerProvider){
            $routerProvider
                .when('/view',{
                    templateUrl: 'view-profile.html',
                    controller: 'UserProfileController'
                })
                .when('/edit',{
                    templateUrl: 'edit-profile.html',
                    controller: 'UserProfileController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/view'
                });
        }
    ]);
```

The above works, i can manually enter /view or /edit in the browser and it'll load, and work.

I have buttons on my page to switch the UI, and when I do, I see the new view, and then it immediately switches back. I'm on /view, I click to change path to edit, and it goes to edit and then back to view. However, when I start on edit, and click to change to view, it sticks. I can then go back to edit fine. It appears to be when the page loads on view.

Here's how I'm changing the views

```
    this.viewProfile = function () {
        $location.path('/view');
    };
    this.editProfile = function () {
        $location.path('/edit');
    };
```

and the buttons look like

On /view

```
<button ng-click="user.editProfile()">Edit My Profile</button>
```

On /edit

```
<button ng-click="user.viewProfile()">Save</button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try with "window.location.href"?

```
window.location.href = "#/view";
```

or something with the Apply?

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $location.path('/view');
});
```

or something with the timeout

```
$timeout(function () {
    $location.path('/bar');
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried those. Just added the route to my page, all I changed/added is above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options here. Instead of buttons, you can use  with href tag to point to where you want to go

```
<a href="/edit">Edit My Profile</a>
```

The other option is to use $scope.$apply() after $location.path(). I think it works fine but I think the first option better.